# Margin in top and bottom of my image in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, header

I have made at Jquery Mobile App.
In the header, I have added at img, but there is a margin on the top and bottem. How do I remove this?

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
<img border="1" src="../images/icon/touch-icon-iphone-114.png" width="50em" alt="Logo, broes" style="float:left;display:inline;margin-left:0px;"/>
<h1 style="text-align:right; margin-right:10px;">Hi All</h1>
</div>
```

Hi All

Comment: Try setting your image to `display:block` instead of `inline`

Comment: I didnt work... I've just found a nother image instead.